# Mobile Forms are Small

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-website

I have a mobile version of a webpage. All it has is a single form w/ two text boxes and one submit button.

But on the mobile browser, the form is tiny until you zoom in on it. How do you make a form look normal by default on a mobile browser?

Comment: Unless you show some code or a live example, I doubt there is not much one can help with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your Doctype mobile?
Try using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

so that phone's browser would know that page is designed for mobile phones

Answer (score 6):

With the meta viewport, I use the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

This way, there is no restriction on the width, so it can adjust accordingly whether the user is using a mobile phone or an iPad (or other tablet device). I would only recommend using the `user-scale=no` if you are building a site specifically for mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the viewport meta tag to the HTML header.  This will tell the browser that your page is suppose to be rendered into a certain aspect. e.g.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=240,user-scalable=no" />
```